# finding time complexity of recurrence relation in algorithms

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Can anyone help me finding the time complexity of

T(n)=1 if n<=0
T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+n

Comment: What are your base cases? n <= 0?

Comment: zero accepted answers and zero upvotes? no way

Answer (score 2):

Consider

```
F(n) = T(n) + n + 3.
```

This gives us

```
F(n) - (n+3) = F(n-1) - (n-1+3)  + F(n-2) - (n-2+3) + n

i.e

F(n) - 3 = F(n-1) - 2 + F(n-2) - 1

i.e

F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)
```

which is a Fibonacci like sequence!

It is well known that for fibonacci like sequences, `F(n) = Theta(phi^n)` where phi is the golden ratio.

Comment: I agree with the conclusion, but I think the proof is wrong: the “i.e.” part is incorrect.

Comment: @Svick: It is basic arithmetic! I didn't say it was _the_ fibonacci sequence. The terms are different.

Comment: @Moron: Yeah, it basic arithmetic, but `(n+1) != (n-1)` and you can't just ignore that.

Comment: @svick: You are right! I have edited the answer. Thanks for pointing the error. I do need new eyes! To be fair (to myself I suppose :-)), those constant terms can be ignored when talking about BigOh. i.e F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) + K has same asymptotics as fibonacci.

Comment: @svick: btw, sorry about that. I should have been more careful, especially after when you were kind enough to comment.

Answer (score 0):

According to [OEIS](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A066982), the closed formula for this function is [image], which means that the asymptotic complexity of this functions is [image].